# Extremely simple formula crashes my program after I insert a line beneath the referenced cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I originally had code, but now I deleted all code in that project. I have a formula in sheet1 that goes "='Sheet2'!I10". Cool, I save its ok. But the moment that I insert a line beneath I10 on sheet2 and then I go back to Sheet1 click into the formula and do nothing but press the check mark the entire program crashses. With an APPCRASH report...... WHY

```
        My Error Report: 
        Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
        Application Name: Excel.EXE
        Application Version:  14.0.7179.5000
        Application Timestamp:    58a5e2fb
        Fault Module Name:    EXCEL.EXE
        Fault Module Version: 14.0.7179.5000
        Fault Module Timestamp:   58a5e2fb
        Exception Code:   c0000005
        Exception Offset: 00261b14
        OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
        Locale ID:    1033
```

Comment: I saw this post, but am not going to answer because I don't know why this is happening... Most people don't either. I think you need to try re-installing or repairing Office/Excel?? At least I had the gall....

Comment: Hahaha thank you! honestly though it was just a little frustrating seeing more and more views but no help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I removed the latest security update from Excel and the code is working again. The code simply remakes a formula after a reference is deleted. Can't understand it. Hopefully Microsoft will fix this.

Comment: I can't help you.  (I can reproduce the problem on my personal computer, but not on my work computer.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments you guys its greatly appreciated!!! @YowE3K Thank you for at least letting me know. Whats weird is I am the opposite I can work on the spreadsheet on my laptop no problem but not on my work computer!!!

Comment: @Dave how did you remove the lates security update

Comment: I have Excel 2010 on my personal computer, but Excel 2013 on my work computer - so nqramjets answer explains why my personal computer doesn't work and work one does.

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is for "my code doesn't work because MS applied a patch and broke it" type questions.  One hopes that MS will fix the issue soon, and then the question should be closed as "not reproducible" but, until then, maybe someone else will stumble across it who has the same problem and the answer will at least tell them that they haven't gone crazy.

Comment: This may seem silly but.. how do I close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough rep to comment... Also don't have a solution.

NOTE: Excel 2010 appears to be the only one affected. (Both x86 and x64). 2013 and 2016 seem to be okay.

**Broken by: KB3178688**

Yes, I'm having the exact same issue at the exact same offset (for 32 bit at least).

For us this also appears to have started recently after running the most recent security patches.

Sorry to spam this, but it's trivial to recreate it. The cell with the formula must reside on another sheet though.

1. Put a number in Sheet1 Cell A1
2. Go to sheet 2 and set a cell formula which is =Sheet1!A1
3. Go to Sheet 1 and add a row below Cell A1
4. Go to Sheet 2 and attempt to delete or modify the cell with a formula
5. Excel crashes

Comment: Thank you for the reply @nqramjets it is greatly appreciated and nice to know I am not the only one. I just would like to know some way to fix this even if its temporarily

Comment: @Googlesoar In our case we're doing automation and adding rows programmatically, so it promptly exploded... Besides introducing a new computed cell there's nothing else I can think of until it's resolved.

Comment: FYI the fix is out. Check Windows Update to pull it.

Comment: You are the GOAT

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to nqramjets for assisting me on this question I have found that the main problem that caused this was a security patch from windows which is **KB3178690**. After uninstalling this, go to control panel->Uninstall a program -> on the left find & click view installed updates -> and find the above mentioned update number under Microsoft Office, and uninstall.

Furthermore there is a new update from Windows that is meant to fix this crazy bug, -> **KB3191855**, install this.

This information can be seen on the Microsoft community page, link below.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/inserting-a-new-line-beneath-a-referenced-cell/d4c50c1e-6141-4f6f-b847-6586fe5d23a8.

Thanks again for everyone's help!
    - Googlesoar